# How do I display all records from a SQL table and match those records to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have set the PHP variable $accountnumber to be that of the user who is viewing their profile page. On the page, I have a block with the user's information populated from the database, and I have a list of all products that we have, and I want to put a check mark next to each one that the customer has by assigning a class to it.

Here are my tables:

```
products
id | name | url    | weight
100  p1     p1.html  1
101  p2     p2.html  2
102  p3     p3.html  3
103  p4     p4.html  4
104  p5     p5.html  5
105  p6     p6.html  6

products_accounts
account_number | product_id
0000001           100
0000001           104
0000001           105
0000002           101
0000002           103
0000002           104
0000002           105
0000003           100
0000003           102
```

I tried a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but was not able to determine if the $accountnumber matched an account_number in the products_accounts table for a specific product_id. The only way that I was able to accomplish this was to add a WHERE statement like this:

```
WHERE products_acccounts.account_number = '$accountnumber'
```

It gave the proper class to the product, but only showed the product that they had instead of all.

Here's my code:

```
$sql ="
SELECT
    products.id,
    products.name,
    products.url,
    products_accounts.account_number
FROM
    products
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    products_accounts
ON
    products.id = products_accounts.product_id

";

$sql .="
GROUP BY
    products.id
ORDER BY
    products.weight
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<span class="'; if($row['account_number'] == '$accountnumber')
    { echo'product_yes">'; } else { echo 'product_no">'; }
    echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a><br /></span>';
}
```

If a customer has all product except P2 and P5, it SHOULD display like this:

> ✓P1
>
> ```
> P2
>
> ✓P3
>
> ✓P4
>
> P5
>
> ✓P6
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$getproducts = mysql_query("
SELECT id, name, url
FROM products
ORDER BY weight ASC");

while ($rowproducts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getproducts)) {

$product_id = $rowproduct['id'];
$product_name = $rowproduct['name'];
$product_url = $rowproduct['url'];

$getuserhasproduct = mysql_query("
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM products_accounts
WHERE account_number = $accountnumber
AND product_id = $product_id");
$user_has_product = mysql_num_rows($getuserhasproduct);

if($user_has_product){
$class = "checked";
}

echo "<span class='$class'><a href='$product_url'>$product_name</a></span>";
unset($class);
} // end loop
```

This might help with performance

```
$getproducts = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, url,
(SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM products_accounts
WHERE account_number = '$accountnumber'
AND product_id = products.id) AS product_count
FROM products
ORDER BY weight ASC");

while ($rowproducts = mysql_fetch_assoc($getproducts)) {

$product_id = $rowproduct['id'];
$product_name = $rowproduct['name'];
$product_url = $rowproduct['url'];
$product_count = $rowproduct['product_count'];

if($product_count > 0){
$class = "checked";
}

echo "<span class='$class'><a href='$product_url'>$product_name</a></span>";
unset($class);
} // end loop
```

Comment: I had a good feeling about this! :) And I was right! You were right! I copied and pasted this into my text editor and only had to fix three things for it to work!

_1. Fixed a typographical error - pluralized "rowproducts" to match the while statement ......_

_2. Added a single quote around the values in "WHERE account_number = '$accountnumber' AND product_id = '$product_id'" ......_

_3.Changed the $class to the one that I already had setup and added "} else { $class = 'product_no'; }_

Comment: I knew you were gonna fix the class one, not sure if the second fix was necessary because it always works fine for me but then again MySQL can be funky sometimes! Good catch on the first edit, that's me trying to type fast and act like I'm not on this website while I'm at work :)

Comment: Yeah, it was necessary. Without it, everything was checked. My first attempt before trying the left outer join was to do something of this method - put a query in the while statement, but I didn't do it quite right, so I thought that the method was wrong all together. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: BTW - thanks for being on this website while you're at work! Saved my day! :)

Comment: oh no problem :) *looks cautiously over shoulder*

Comment: this is going to be much slower than handling the filtering in the sql statement directly. you might want to consider one of the pure sql solutions in one of the other answers for performance's sake

Answer (score 2):

It's better to filter out rows using SQL than PHP, like below:

```
$sql ="
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.name,
    p.url,
    pa.account_number
FROM
    products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    products_accounts pa
ON
    p.id = pa.product_id
    AND
    pa.account_number = ".mysql_real_escape_string($accountnumber)."
ORDER BY
    p.weight
";


$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<span class="'; if(!is_null($row['account_number']))
    { echo'product_yes">'; } else { echo 'product_no">'; }
    echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a><br /></span>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    products.id,
    products.name,
    products.url,
    products_accounts.account_number
FROM
    products
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM products_accounts WHERE account_number = $account_number) as products
ON
    products.id = products_accounts.product_id
WHERE 
";

$sql .="
GROUP BY
    products.id
ORDER BY
    products.weight
";
```

i think this is your answer, you need to filter your join table before the join. please check the syntax as i am not that familiar with php.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `GROUP BY` in a context that doesn't make sense if you want to retrieve all of the records.  The `GROUP BY` clause should only be used if you want to aggregate data (i.e. get the sum, average, etc. of a bunch of records).

Comment: No, if I do not use `GROUP BY`, It will display each product for as many times as it shows up in the products_accounts table.

Comment: I want to display each product ONCE. For the products that the user has, it should apply a class to it.

For a user having all products except P2 and P5, it would be displayed like this:

`✓P1
P2
✓P3
✓P4
P5
✓P6`

Comment: @nitsuj: You can't use `GROUP BY` and select column data that isn't aggregated; the results will not make any sense...

Comment: The results are making sense though. It is displaying all of the products just like I want for it to be - I just need to assign a class to the products that are included in a record with the account id. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @nitsuj: No, they aren't.  You're getting back a random `account_number` for each `product_id` for products with multiple accounts.  In your example data, for `product_id` 105, there are two `account_number`s: 000001 and 000002.  Your query will only return 1 of those 2 `account_number`s at random, because you used `GROUP BY`.